# sublime 3.0 UI is broken after update 3143

Tags: sublimetext3

See attached screenshot.  The whole UI is broken with rainbow like blocks. Top tab is not clickable now.

I have tried to revert back to 3126(by replacing .exe file), but still has the same problem.  I don't want to do a fresh install because there has been a bunch of packages configured over time.

How do I fix it?

I am using Windows 10.

[image]